# Unity c# - cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action<EventManager.Event>'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

## **Situation**

I have a basic event management system in my unity app and I'm trying to get it to let me dispatch custom events that subclass `EventManager.Event` rather than having to cast custom event inside my handlers.

**Current Working Example**

```
//PinchScale.cs
int zoomLevel = Random.Range(1, 10);
EventManager.TriggerEvent(new ZoomEvent(zoomLevel));
```

---

```
// Earth.cs
void ZoomEventHandler(EventManager.Event e)
{
    int zoomLevel = ((PinchScale.ZoomEvent)e).zoomLevel;
    // do some stuff
}
```

**Desired Example**

```
void ZoomEventHandler(PinchScale.ZoomEvent e)
{
    this.LoadTiles(e.zoomLevel);
}
```

**Error with Desired Example**

```
Assets\Scripts\Earth.cs(23,52): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action<EventManager.Event>'
```

## **Question**

Is it possible to use the desired example with c# ? I assumed so because `PinchScale.ZoomEvent` subclasses `EventManager.Event`.

***additional code below***

**EventManager.cs**

```
...

public static void StartListening(string eventType, Action<EventManager.Event> listener)
{
    if (!EventManager.instance)
    {
        Debug
            .LogError("EventManager has not been initted. Is there one added to your scene yet?");
        return;
    }

    EventListenerPair pair = new EventListenerPair(eventType, listener);
    EventManager.instance.eventDictionary.Add (pair);
}

public static void StopListening(string eventType, Action<EventManager.Event> listener)
{
    if (
        EventManager.instance == null ||
        EventManager.instance.eventDictionary.Count <= 0
    ) return;

    Array d = EventManager.instance.eventDictionary.ToArray();
    foreach (EventListenerPair e in d)
    {
        if (e.eventType == eventType && e.listener == listener)
            EventManager.instance.eventDictionary.Remove(e);
    }

    //Debug.Log("event listener count: " + EventManager.instance.eventDictionary.Count);
}

public static void TriggerEvent(EventManager.Event e)
{
    if (
        EventManager.instance == null ||
        EventManager.instance.eventDictionary.Count <= 0
    ) return;
    Array d = EventManager.instance.eventDictionary.ToArray();
    foreach (EventListenerPair pair in d)
    {
        // if (pair.eventType == e.type) pair.listener.Invoke(e);
        if (pair.eventType == e.type) pair.listener(e);
    }
}

public class Event
{
    public string type;

    public Event(string type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class EventListenerPair
{
    public string eventType;

    public Action<EventManager.Event> listener;

    public EventListenerPair(string eventType, Action<EventManager.Event> listener)
    {
        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}

...
```

**PinchScale.cs**

```
...

public class ZoomEvent : EventManager.Event
{
    public int zoomLevel;

    public ZoomEvent(int zoomLevel = 0) :
        base(PinchScale.ZOOM_EVENT)
    {
        this.zoomLevel = zoomLevel;
    }
}

...
```

**Earth.cs**

```
...

void Start() {
    EventManager.StartListening(PinchScale.ZOOM_EVENT, this.ZoomEventHandler);
}

...

void ZoomEventHandler(PinchScale.ZoomEvent e)
{
    int zoomLevel = ((PinchScale.ZoomEvent)e).zoomLevel;
    // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: `PinchScale.ZoomEvent zoomEvent = e as PinchScale.ZoomEvent; ` is this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, `PinchScale.ZoomEvent` subclasses `EventManager.Event`, but `Action<EventManager.Event>` doesn't subclass `Action<PinchScale.ZoomEvent>`. If it worked that way, that would kind of imply multiple inheritance (since generic class would than derive both from its own base class (`Delegate` in this case?) and from another generic class(`Action<EventManager.Event>`)), which is, I believe, not allowed in C#.

You can, however, make your StartListening and StopListening methods generic, like that:

```
public static void StartListening<T>(string eventType, Action<T> listener) where T : EventManager.Event 
{
    //handle the type differences here
}
```

Then you can use it sort of like you wanted, but you will have to explicitly state the type for generics when calling, since it can't be inferred:

```
EventManager.StartListening<PinchScale.ZoomEvent>(PinchScale.ZOOM_EVENT, this.ZoomEventHandler);
```

And of course when dispatching events you will also have to convert the argument for them to their accepted type, but this time the responsibility for that will be on `EventManager`, not on the listener.

A quick mockup (I added the type argument to Dispatch to force the user to explicitly state what event should be dispatched. That's just my preference, you can just convert the event without it):

```
public class BaseEvent {}

public class DerivedEvent : BaseEvent {}

public class AnotherDerivedEvent : BaseEvent {}

class EventManager
{
    static Dictionary<BaseEvent, List<Delegate>> subscribers = new Dictionary<BaseEvent, List<Delegate>>();
    
    public static void StartListening<T>(BaseEvent @event, Action<T> arg) where T : BaseEvent
    {
        Action<BaseEvent> convertedAction = (BaseEvent be) => arg((T)be);
        if (!subscribers.ContainsKey(@event))
            subscribers.Add(@event, new List<Delegate>() { arg });
        else
            subscribers[@event].Add(arg);
    }   
    
    public static void Dispatch<T>(BaseEvent @event) where T : BaseEvent
    { 
        if (subscribers.ContainsKey(@event))
            foreach (var sub in subscribers[@event])
            {
                if (sub.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0] != typeof(T)) //check that we didn't call with wrong type
                    throw new ArgumentException("Event not matching subscriber!");
                var action = (sub as Action<T>);
                action((T)@event);
            }           
    }   
}
```

And usage:

```
var a = new A();
var e = new DerivedEvent(); 
var e2 = new AnotherDerivedEvent();
EventManager.StartListening<DerivedEvent>(e, a.DoThing);
EventManager.Dispatch<DerivedEvent>(e); // output: Reacting to event!
EventManager.Dispatch<AnotherDerivedEvent>(e); // this line throws, because we used the wrong type argument
```

(class A)

```
class A 
{
    public void DoThing(DerivedEvent arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reacting to event!");
    }
}
```